# Accumulating values from SQL database table that refers to itself

Tags: sql, recursion, relationship

**TASK**

I am currently trying to work out a viable structure for a simple application for the costing of jobs. I have decided to create one table to house all the operations and then link the operation together via a ParentID field. Below is a simplified structure of this table:

[image: Simplified structure of my DB table]

As you can see, the primary key is an integer field that does auto increment to keep it unique. Any operations that stem off another operation will have it under the parent ID field to create a simplistic breakdown of work flow. Also on this data table is a field for costs, this is a field that I am most interested in.

**THE PROBLEM**

I would like  to run a query where I could throw in an operation ID and it would recursively run through that operation AND all of its children and its children's children etc. This would then accumulate all of the cost fields in the records that it retrieves. The only way I can think to do this is through recursive loops which in my opinion are not the best way to do this.

**THE QUESTION**

So, my question is, is there a way to do this without recursive loops? If there is not, can anyone suggest the cleanest and quickest way with the loops?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of query is recursive by definition. There is no way to get that information using that table structure.

You *could* make another table in which you would store all hierarchy information. On inserting an `Operation` you would have to add a parent, grandparent, grand-...-parent recursively, which may also not be a good idea, because the table would grow very large very quickly. It would make the queries much simpler though.

And a side note: I'd suggest naming the `ParentID` `ParentOperationID`. `ParentID` is too general.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would still like to explore the query route and what would be involved in that, as the option you suggested does still have issues with respect to inserting records. Plus future functionality of copying and pasting operations would be made a lot harder.

Comment: @Weebie no problem. I have no proof, but I think that non-recursion version is impossible for this type of hierarchy.